# Is cold plasma safe?

Tags: air-quality, environmental-conditions

An HVAC installer is recommending cold plasma to fix HVAC systems with [Dirty Sock Syndrome](https://asm-air.com/airconditioning/dirty-sock-syndrome-what-is-it-dangerous/).

But are the ions generated by [cold plasma generating systems](http://topproductinnovations.com/main.html) safe themselves?

If I recall correctly, [Sharper Image was sued over their air purifiers](http://www.airpurifierguide.org/faq/what-happened-to-ionic-breeze) that generated ions due to health effects.  Those weren't cold plasma generators, however.